# Difference between ActiveChart.Copy and ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

What is the difference between ActiveChart.Copy and ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy? I have a macro that copies 20+ charts from Excel to PowerPoint. They both seem to produce the same result when pasted into PowerPoint, but is one considered best practice over the other? Is there a difference in memory or performance? I am trying to make my sub as lean as possible.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartarea(object))? Seems like either one is fine for your purpose.

Comment: For "lean as possible", choose ActiveChart.Copy. It's shorter, and every dot in a VBA command takes a tiny amount of extra time to execute.